# VueJS 2 Как привязать данные в родителе к ребенку(компонент)

Tags: vue.js

```
Vue.component('range-slider', {
    props: ['name', 'min', 'max'],
    template: '<div class="form-group"> ' +
                    '<label class="control-label">{{name}}</label>' +


                    '<input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="value(тут value это initialPayment, либо monthyPayment)" v-on:keypress="isNumber($event)"> ' +
                    '<vue-slider ref="slider"' +
                        'v-model="value"' +
                        ':tooltip="false"'+
                        ':min="parseInt(min, 10)"' +
                        ':max="parseInt(max, 10)">' +
                    '</vue-slider>' +
              '</div>',
    components: {
        'vueSlider': window[ 'vue-slider-component' ]
    }
});

new Vue({
    el: '.app',
    data: {
        initialPayment: 10,
        monthyPayment: 0,
    }
});

<div class="app">
    <range-slider 
      name="Текст" 
      min="10"
      max="1000"
      // Как то передать initialPayment>
   </range-slider>

    <range-slider 
      name="Текст" 
      min="10"
      max="1000">
      // Как то передать monthyPayment
    </range-slider>
</div>
```

Необходимо сцепить родительские данные с данными ребенка, представленного в виде компонента. А точнее с input внутри компонента.
И при изменении данных в input, родительский блок понимал что изменилось например initialPayment, и запускал какой нибудь пересчет либо computed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для таких целей существует генератор событий, во `Vue` имя ему `EventBus`. В проекте Вы можете создать папку `events` и файл `index.ts` в котором определить этот генератор:

```
export const $bus = new Vue();
```

Либо если Вы работаете без какого либо сборщика модулей - определите этот генератор в прототипе `Vue`:

```
Vue.prototype.$bus = new Vue();
```

В шаблоне дочернего компонента, повесьте обработчик события на инпут:

```
<input name="initialPayment" @keyup="changeInitialPayment($event.target.value)">
```

В компоненте определяем этот метод и генерируем событие:

```
methods: {
    changeInitialPayment(value) {
        this.$bus.$emit('changeInitialPayment', value);
    }
}
```

В родителе слушаем событие `changeInitialPayment`:

```
mounted() {
    this.$bus.$on('changeInitialPayment', (value) => {
        console.log(value);
        // Делайте что-то с новым значением `initialPayment`
    });
}
```

Comment: чем это отличается от обычного $emit, $on - зачем допонительная обертка

Comment: это не доп. обертка, это абстракция и подход, которые советует использовать `Vue` команда

Comment: @ruslik, тут тогда вопрос - в чем заключается Ваш вопрос? Если Вы знаете про генерацию событий, то какой ответ Вы хотите получить? Просто Ваш вопрос прозвучал так `Необходимо сцепить родительские данные с данными ребенка, представленного в виде компонента. А точнее с input внутри компонента. `

Comment: тогда вопрос в том что правильно ли я вообще делаю и нужны ли тут триггеры событий? Нельзя ли просто как-то передавать в ребенка данные, и чтобы изменения этих данных отлавливал родитель. Почему надо именно триггерить события. Я могу как-то передать в компонент данные родителя как ссылку, затем в ребенке меняются значения данных. Так как данные переданы по ссылке, родитель видит изименения этих данных и запускает свои события или обновляет вычисляемые свойства у себя

Comment: @ruslik, смотрите, здесь несколько вариантов как это реализовать, самый быстрый и простой это использовать `EventBus`, но если хотите еще больше разделить ответственность и абстрагировать логику - используйте `Vuex`, я думаю Вам не составит труда настроить его под Ваши нужды

Comment: нет, у меня формочка маленькая из 3 полей, я думаю vuex тут не нужен

Comment: тогда в чем проблема? используйте генерацию событий, такое общение между родителем и ребенком работает в любой библиотеке и фреймворке, родитель передает данные ребенку через байндинги, а ребенок общается с родителем через генерацию событий, по-другому никак

Comment: Спасибо, просто до этого не приходилось работать с фреймворками. Поэтому нет понимания как правильно а как нет

Comment: `Vue` это не фреймворк, а `ATE (advanced templating engine)`, подход с генерацией событий правильный, но на начальных этапах, если у Вас недостаточно опыта, делайте как Вам удобно, понимание придет со временем. Cheers :-)